# Filter data highlighted in Excel by cell fill color using openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, highlight, openxlsx

I have a big Excel table (18k rows and 400 cols) which has some rows highlighted using different colors. Is there a way to filter the rows by colors using `openxlsx`?

I first loaded the workbook

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "Items Comparison.xlsx")
getStyles(wb)
df <- read.xlsx(wb, sheet = 1)
```

I see the styles used in the workbook using `getStyles(wb)`, but not sure how to use that information to filter all cells for each column by colors.

```
[[1]]
A custom cell style. 

 Cell formatting: GENERAL 
 Font name: Tahoma 
 Font size: 9 
 Font colour: #FFFFFF 
 Font decoration: BOLD 
 Cell borders: Top: thin, Bottom: thin, Left: thin, Right: thin 
 Cell border colours: #4E648A, #4E648A, #4E648A, #4E648A 
 Cell vert. align: top 
 Cell fill foreground:  rgb: #384C70 
 Cell fill background:  rgb: #384C70 
 wraptext: TRUE 


[[2]]
A custom cell style. 

 Cell formatting: GENERAL 
 Font name: Tahoma 
 Font size: 9 
 Font colour: #FFFFFF 
 Font decoration: BOLD 
 Cell borders: Top: thin, Bottom: thin, Left: thin, Right: thin 
 Cell border colours: #4E648A, #4E648A, #4E648A, #4E648A 
 Cell vert. align: top 
 Cell fill foreground:  rgb: #384C70 
 Cell fill background:  rgb: #384C70 
 wraptext: TRUE
```

What can I do to filter data by fill colors?

**UPDATE**

Based on @Henrik solution, I tried to use his code but I kept getting error. So, to understand what was going on, I printed the output of `x$style$fill$fillFg`

```
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 
NULL
NULL
NULL
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 
 theme 
   "0" 
 theme 
   "0" 
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 
NULL
 theme 
   "2" 
                theme                  tint 
                  "4" "0.79998168889431442" 
 theme 
   "8" 
 theme 
   "8" 
       rgb 
"FFFFC000" 
       rgb 
"FFFFC000" 
                theme                  tint 
                  "5" "0.39997558519241921" 
                theme                  tint 
                  "5" "0.39997558519241921" 
                theme                  tint 
                  "9" "0.39997558519241921" 
                theme                  tint 
                  "5" "0.79998168889431442" 
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 
NULL
NULL
NULL
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 
[[1]]
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 

[[2]]
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
NULL

[[11]]
NULL

[[12]]
NULL

[[13]]
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 

[[14]]
NULL

[[15]]
NULL

[[16]]
NULL

[[17]]
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 

[[18]]
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 

[[19]]
 theme 
   "0" 

[[20]]
 theme 
   "0" 

[[21]]
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 

[[22]]
NULL

[[23]]
 theme 
   "2" 

[[24]]
                theme                  tint 
                  "4" "0.79998168889431442" 

[[25]]
 theme 
   "8" 

[[26]]
 theme 
   "8" 

[[27]]
       rgb 
"FFFFC000" 

[[28]]
       rgb 
"FFFFC000" 

[[29]]
                theme                  tint 
                  "5" "0.39997558519241921" 

[[30]]
                theme                  tint 
                  "5" "0.39997558519241921" 

[[31]]
                theme                  tint 
                  "9" "0.39997558519241921" 

[[32]]
                theme                  tint 
                  "5" "0.79998168889431442" 

[[33]]
       rgb 
"FFFFFF00" 

[[34]]
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 

[[35]]
NULL

[[36]]
NULL

[[37]]
NULL

[[38]]
       rgb 
"FF384C70" 

[[39]]
       rgb 
"FF384C70"
```

I'm still confused why there're only 39 items. total number of rows is variable but not 39. I'm also not understanding the operation - is it rowwise or columnwise?

Comment: Does it have to be the openxlsx-package, or are other packages an option?

Comment: other packages are also an option. I just found tidyxl which I'm looking at right now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
library(tidyxl)

formats <- xlsx_formats( "./temp/test_file.xlsx" )
cells <- xlsx_cells( "./temp/test_file.xlsx" )

#what colors are used?
formats$local$fill$patternFill$fgColor$rgb
# [1] NA         "FFC00000" "FF00B0F0" NA  

#find rows fo cells  with red background
cells[ cells$local_format_id %in%
         which( formats$local$fill$patternFill$fgColor$rgb == "FFC00000"), 
       "row" ]

# [1] 1
```

Comment: this is great. This is what I was also reading about. Thanks. I'll let you know what I get from this

Comment: turned out it's actually much simpler than this. I followed @nacnudus [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sinC7wsS5U) and saw how easy it is to filter based on the color. My intention was to simply filter the cells with any colors like the following. `cells %>% behead("N", "program") %>% select(address, row, col, character, program, style_format, local_format_id) %>% filter(!is.na(fill[local_format_id]))`.  I'm accepting your response as answer for pointing me to this direction.

Answer (score 2):

In your workbook object, you find the `styleObjects` element. There you can dig your way to the fill color (`style$fill$fillFg`) and `row` elements. Loop over the style objects (`lapply`), check if the color is desired one (e.g. red, "FFFF0000"; `x$style$fill$fillFg == "FFFF0000"`, and grab the row index (`x$rows[1]`).

[image]

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "foo.xlsx")
unlist(lapply(wb$styleObjects, function(x){
  x$rows[1][x$style$fill$fillFg == "FFFF0000"]}))

# [1] 3
```

---

If the colored cells are non-contiguous, you may want to grab both rows and columns:

[image]

```
l = lapply(wb$styleObjects, function(x){
  if(x$style$fill$fillFg == "FFFF0000"){
    data.frame(ri = x$rows, ci = x$cols, col = "FFFF0000")}})
l[lengths(l) > 0]

# [[1]]
#   ri ci      col
# 1  1  2 FFFF0000
# 2  2  3 FFFF0000
# 3  3  1 FFFF0000
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I'm getting some errors: `Error in if (x$style$fill$fillFg == "FFFF0000") { : argument is of length zero`.  I updated my question to show the output of `x$style$fill$fillFg`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My second example was apparently not of sufficient complexity. Can you please update your question with a _truly minimal_ reproducible example which illustrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using openxlsx package
Example below looks for color "FFC000" and looks in columns 1 and 6
The approach first identifies which defined styles have the font color of interest, then looks through the style objects to see which cells those styles have been applied to, returning the index of the rows that match the color and the pre-defined column search.  The result would give all rows where at least one cell within the column search has the specified color.

```
excelwb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(excel_file)
strikestyles <- getStyles(excelwb)
goldcolors <- which(sapply(strikestyles,'[[','fontColour')=="FFFFC000") 
goldcols <- c(1,6) #these are the columns that have the gold color of interest -- could also be 1:ncol
goldrows <- lapply(excelwb$styleObjects[goldcolors],
                     function(x) {
                       value_cols <- which(x$cols %in% goldcols) 
                       if (length(value_cols)==0) return(NULL)
                       else return (x$rows[value_cols])
                     })
goldrows <- as.numeric(unlist(goldrows))
```